# How can i upload data into sql,If that data is selected by checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays

i create form for user select the desired data by checkbox
i have data table from sql

```
<script>
$('input[type=checkbox]').live("change",function(){
    var target = $(this).parent().find('input[type=hidden]').val();
    if(target == 0)
    {
        target = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        target = 0;
    }
    $(this).parent().find('input[type=hidden]').val(target);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
<form id= "MyForm" method= "POST" action= "test_save.php">
<table width="70%" border="1" id="myTable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="5%"><div align="center">NO.</div></th>
    <th width="10%"><div align="center">ACCOUNT CODE</div></th>
    <th width="25%"><div align="center">ITEM NAME</div></th>
    <th width="5%"><div align="center"></div></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

<?php

$i=0;

while($i<$numr && $ven2 = $ven->fetch_assoc())
{$i++;

?>
<tr> 
<td><center><?php echo $ven2["id"]; ?></center></td>
<td><center><?php echo $ven2["acc_name"]; ?></center></td>
<td><?php echo $ven2["item_name"]; ?></td>
<td><center><input type="checkbox" ><input type="hidden" name="dataset[]" value="0" ></center></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody> 
</table>
```

if checkbox == 0
i want to keep the select data and upload into another database
amount of the select data will depend on user
no fixed
what should i do
this is sql i dont know how to use which variable for support accountcode and item name

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(~0);

    $serverName = "localhost";
    $userName = "root";
    $userPassword = "1234";
    $dbName = "purchasenewtest";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($serverName,$userName,$userPassword,$dbName);
    mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');

    $data = $dataset[];

    if($data==0) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO r(accountcode,orders) 
        VALUES ('".$_POST["x"]."','".$_POST["y"]."')";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Hi can you at least show the mysql database structure and possibly what you have done that did not work, because it is kind of hard to figure out what you even want to do.